# Create table and save data in backendless (Swift)

Tags: xcode, swift, swift2, backendless

Is there a way to create a table and save data in a backendless.com database with swift2? I found just code for Objective-C.

Objektiv-C code:

```
-(void)saveNewContact
{
  Responder *responder = [Responder responder:self selResponseHandler:@selector(responseHandler:) selErrorHandler:@selector(errorHandler:)];
  Contact *contact = [Contact new];
   contact.age = 21;
   contact.title = @"title";
   contact.name = @"name";
   contact.phone = @"555-555-555";
  id<IDataStore> dataStore = [backendless.persistenceService of:[Contact class]];
   [dataStore save:contact responder:responder];
}
```

URL: https://backendless.com/documentation/data/ios/data_saving_data_objects.htm

Comment: please paste the objective c code, or point us to it with a link.

Comment: The only way ( I know ) is using a bridging header.

Comment: isn't it possible to transform the above code in swift? That doesn't seem so hard

Answer (score 0):

Above code converted to Swift

```
func saveNewContact() {
     var responder: Responder = Responder.responder(self, selResponseHandler: "responseHandler:", selErrorHandler: "errorHandler:")
     var contact: Contact = Contact()
     contact.age = 21
     contact.title = "title"
     contact.name = "name"
     contact.phone = "555-555-555"
     var dataStore: IDataStore = backendless.persistenceService.of(Contact.self)
     dataStore.save(contact, responder: responder)
}
```

Hope this might be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

If you check that page again, there is now example in both Objective C and Swift.